# Creating an efficient way of keep track of many 100's of 1000's of tagged cache id references

Tags: php, mysql, caching, tags

We currently have a table setup to keep track of cache file names or memcached key references. The table exists so that when a comment is added or more content is added the system automatically purges those cache files/key-value pairs that are affected by the update so the rebuild the next time a user accesses the page the user sees the updated content. The current table structure is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cache_references` (
  `cache_id` int(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cache_page_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cache_tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cache_group` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cache_expiry` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cache_id`),
  KEY `cache_page_id` (`cache_page_id`),
  KEY `cache_tag` (`cache_tag`),
  KEY `cache_group` (`cache_group`),
  KEY `cache_expiry` (`cache_expiry`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This is all well and good, however this table gets massive, very very quickly and a moderate sized site, aggressively cached can easily produce over 500,000 cache file references. Whilst this isn't really a problem for small to moderate sites this isn't really the solution for large sites with many pages and assets as it can cause table locks and/or large table scans when searching for the cache page ids to delete.

My question is what would be a possible way to improve on this solution?

Answer (score 0):

first you can change the engine to InnoDB. InnoDB have a per row locking system so you wouldn't have lock problems anymore.